# What is the relationship between virtualhosting and virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am a bit confused about virtualhosting and virtualenv.

I know that virtualenv creates isolated python installations with the packages required for a specific app.  I got that.  That, to me, means that you still need to setup virtuahosts in order to host multiple domains out of a single box.

In a typical VPS each domain user is isolated from access beyond their user account.  This means you cannot create and maintain virtualenvs outside the user space.  Not sure if that throws a wrench in the machine.

For a specific example, let's say you have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin you@example_01.com

  ServerName   example_01.com
  ServerAlias  example_01.com *.example_01.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example_01/public_html
  ErrorLog     /var/www/example_01/logs/access.log
  CustomLog    /var/www/example_01/logs/error.log combined

  <Directory   /var/www/example_01>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin you@example_02.com

  ServerName   example_02.com
  ServerAlias  example_02.com *.example_02.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example_02/public_html
  ErrorLog     /var/www/example_02/logs/access.log
  CustomLog    /var/www/example_02/logs/error.log combined

  <Directory   /var/www/example_02>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does each user then handle and manage their own virtualenv?  In that case they could live at:

```
/var/www/example_01/virtualenv/
```

and

```
/var/www/example_02/virtualenv/
```

Is this the way it is done?

The context, again, is you have a VPS plan and have multiple clients each with their own domains being hosted on that one machine.  How do you setup virtualhosting and virtualenv to cover this scenario?

Comment: I would think you would want something more "sandboxed" than virtualenv.  From what I understand virtualenv just covers what python modules are installed in a given environment.  Nothing to do with separating out networking / execution space / etc.  Virtual machines or, at the very least, kernel level virtualization (lxc,docker,etc) should be used to host multiple clients on a single machine.

Comment: I think you also confuse VPS (user has a whole virtual server for themselves, ie user == root) with shared web hosting (user has a shell account and access to some pre-configured Apache web space like you described).

Comment: @hmn, not sure if your comment was for me. Anyhow, I used "VPS" as shorthand for what I meant and perhaps I wasn't clear enough.  Imagine I get a Linode and then use Virtual Hosting (not virtual machines) to host multiple domains and provide a cPanel type interface for each domain owner to manage their site. How are virtualenvs then managed?  I am new to Python and virtualenv and might very well have a hole in my understanding. So far every tutorial I've come across seems to start from one being the root user as opposed to one of 100 people managing one of 100 sites on a server.

Comment: Virtualenv works through environment variables, those could be set up for the user on login, and in Apache for each virtual host.